# ZK CDATA and passing a variable?

Tags: variables, escaping, cdata, zk

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now and I can't seem to get it right.
Here is my code:

```
<attribute name="onClick"><![CDATA[
Messagebox.show("Remove this file?", "Remove?", Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO, Messagebox.QUESTION,
new EventListener() {
    public void onEvent(Event evt) {
        switch (((Integer)evt.getData()).intValue()) {
            case Messagebox.YES: someFunction(${each.Id}); break;
            case Messagebox.NO: break;
        }
    }
})
]]></attribute>
```

The above code is from a forEach cycle in a ZK ZUL page. It should generate a list of files and on every file you should have a "Delete" button. When you click on it a popup should come up and ask for confirmation. After you confirm it should pass the id to a function which from then handles everything.

I'm quite sure it's something really small I'm missing or not knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. You cannot use EL in zscript. Rather, you have to access it through implicit object. For example,

```
    <window>
      <button label="${each}" forEach="apple, orange">
        <zscript>
      self.parent.appendChild(new Label("" + each));
        </zscript>
      </button>
    </window>
```

1. However, each is available only in the page rendering. It is reset after evaluated. It means, you can't access it in the event listener. For example, the following won't work

```
    <window>
      <button label="${each}" forEach="apple, orange"
        onClick='alert(""+each)'/> 
    </window>
```

You have to store the each object first and then use it in the event listener.

You might take a look at [ZK's reference](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/Iterative_Evaluation)